# dc.js dataTable - how to use a pre-defined group

Tags: datatable, dc.js, crossfilter

I would like to load a dc dataTable with dimensional data that has been grouped and filtered. Is this possible? I am assuming it is but the examples I have seen so far have simple groups coded at the time of table construction and I can't get it to work any other way!

```
var facts = crossfilter(data);
var testTable = dc.dataTable('#testtable');
var providerDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {
   if (d.report_by_3 !== null) {
    return d.report_by_3;
   }
});

var MH003Group = providerDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
  if (d.indicator_code === 'MH003') {
    return (d.observed / d.expected);
  } else {
    return null;
  } 
});

var MH003Group2 = {
  all: function () {
    return MH003Group.all().filter(function (d) {
        return d.value !== null;
    });
  }
};

dataTable.width(960)
  .height(8000)
  .dimension(providerDim)
  // .group(MH003Group2)
  .group(function (d) {
    return 'data';
  })
  .size(10)
  .columns([function (d) {return d.indicator_code;},
            function (d) {return d.report_by_1;},
            function (d) {return d.report_by_3;},
            function (d) {return (d.observed / d.expected);}
   ]);
  .sortBy(function (d) {return d.report_by_1;})
.order(d3.ascending);
```

In the code above I would like to display filtered rows in the dimension using the pre-defined grouping rather than all the rows of data in the dimension which is what is currently happening.